# CF-30 GPS and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: serial-port, gps

I recently purchased a Panasonic CF-30 with the built in factory default GPS module. The GPS feature worked perfectly while still running Windows XP, but i switched over to 14.04 and I cant figure out which device name belongs to the GPS module.

While still running windows XP it was COM3, 4800 baud, and NMEA format

I have tried /dev/ttyS( 1 through 20) and I get nothing.
If anyone could provide some information about this and linux serial devices in general it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The following page describes the setup steps for a Garmin device, however some of the steps are general and might be useful:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GarminGPSMap76CSx

Specifically, there is one serial related setup, and describes tools used to verify connections:

*“If you wish to use the GPS Unit to transmit real-time data to an application such as tangoGPS, xgps, Merkaartor, you must set the transmission protocol to NMEA regardless of which of the three cables (USB, Straight or Y) you are using.
To do this, press the menu button twice to get to the Main Menu, then navigate to Setup then to Interface then to Serial Data Format. Press the Enter button and scroll down to choose NMEA IN/NMEA OUT.”*